# openssl encrypt rsa message into plain text

Tags: bash, openssl

I know it's very trivial but, how i can produce an encrypted plain text message with openssl?

I launch this command but produce a binary file:

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey myPubKey.pem -pubin -in Text.txt -out encText.msg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I launch this command but produce a binary file:
>
> openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey myPubKey.pem -pubin -in Text.txt -out encText.msg

Encrypted text is binary. If you want it encoded, then you have to pipe it through to an encoder like `base64`. There is no `-outform` switch for `rsautil` to do what you want:

```
$ openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey pubrsa.pem -pubin -in Text.txt | base64 > out.b64
$ cat out.b64 
XEmXEIt/GcBHOcW5jVHL6dnVdTB/Tv3xA6f1HOaojwTA75Xil16JVw24JkQy+zFiOs/bEg16EKyysTx
/RgesyKxM9G70ZtfhwnsVyjPpUVNg4/CROhLoJ9C6bnklyvl1nNuBmA3st1n+8bDHO001iEjhCPIGJE
ctVzdKRq8KaH/Ld3b5rbV8L0yfx4CkcRjycWrQ5BMyL5U3eNVouHs7OQW006k97mD9QkZSyezyWPU1K
1AjAd2zzS6X0PSd6a3wYjoFPOCOtvrMGn2zJQS0KYJRkPinfp+zZOUQKwWBkMgwdQV4aaYXtx57HSSc
6x7s53Ngbyg4KvoQRirzSEhYA==
```

Answer (score 0):

you must look [here](http://sandilands.info/sgordon/demo-of-symmetric-key-encryption-using-openssl) which explain how to encrypt plain text message using opnssl.